# How do I generate documentation using rvm after a reinstall?

Tags: documentation, rvm

I installed RVM as per the instructions on http://rvm.io. Here's what I've done:  **`rvm list`**:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Followed by a **`ruby -v`**:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

And then a **`rvm docs generate`**:

```
Currently 'rvm docs ...' does not work with non-rvm rubies.
```

I then tried **`rvm reinstall 1.9.3 && rvm docs generate`**. This resulted in the rvm giving me the above error.

**How do I generate docs with rvm?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the rvm binary (i.e. I did not build it from sources). See [this git issue](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1195) for more details. Doing a `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --disable-binary` will build rvm from source and allow you to generate docs with rvm. (At least for version 1.9.3)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ruby first:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

Comment: I did `rvm use 1.9.3` and then `rvm docs generate` and I still got the same error.

Comment: are you using rvm 1.16 with zsh? this might be known issue: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues - make sure to comment on existing or open new one ... and if it is the case using bash or older version could help: `rvm get 1.15.10`

Comment: No. I'm using rvm 1.16.6 with bash. I'll try rolling back to 1.15.10…

Comment: I looked at the issues as per your suggestion. I'll post back here once it gets resolved there. Thanks mpapis!