# Getting source of ruby 1.9.3 using rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed ruby 1.9.3 on Mountain Lion using:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

This all worked fine and I can now use ruby 1.9.3. However, in the .rvm/src directory I usually had a folder named ruby-1.9.3p123 which held the source code of my ruby installation. Such a folder doesn't exist any more. I guess rvm installed ruby using some precompiled binaries, but how can I force it to compile from source or at least get me the source code?

Comment: Maybe sources have been cleared. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667445/how-do-i-generate-documentation-using-rvm-after-a-reinstall and other posts.

Comment: Also _Provided you have not cleaned up the extracted sources..._ in https://rvm.io/rubies/docs/ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625631/nothing-known-about-when-trying-ri-stringupcase-ruby

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes RVM tries to install binaries first, it's faster.

for installing source only try:

```
rvm fetch 1.9.3
```

for installing ruby from souce:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --disable-binary
```